# What's the difference between a Gradle Plugin that requires an explicit classpath and one that doesn't?

Tags: java, kotlin, gradle, groovy

What's the difference between a Gradle Plugin that requires an explicit classpath and one that doesn't?

Also, how do I create a Gradle Plugin that doesn't require an explicit classpath specification?

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.4.1'
    }
```

```
plugins {
    id "com.cookpad.android.plugin.license-tools" version "1.2.5" // Plugin that does not require explicit classpath specification
    id "com.google.firebase.crashlytics" // Plugin that requires explicit classpath specification
}
```

Comment: `plugins` is the new way and at least of 6.8 still both are supported.  The docs show how to create a plugin: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_plugins.html

Answer (score 1):

> For core Gradle plugins or plugins already available to the build
> script

```
id «plugin id»
```

> For binary Gradle plugins that need to be resolved

```
id «plugin id» version «plugin version» [apply «false»]
```

[You can refer this official documentation for further information](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#sec:constrained_syntax)